hacer un menú sin molerla
Holaaaa, tengo una duda, estoy empezando con esto de python, pero al momento de hacer un menú, en vez de que finalice cuando termina de hacer la operación quiero que regrese al menú principal, y que el usuario decida se hacer otra operación o salir, alguien sabe dónde puedo encontrar documentación sobre eso, o algo que me pueda ayudar, inserto codigo:
op=int(input(print('Escoje una opción'+'\n1.-Suma'+'\n2.-Resta'+'\n3.-Multiplicación'+'\n4.-Division'+'\n"5/0".-Salirs')))
while op != 0:
    if op==1:
        n1=int(input(print('Escoge tu primer numero')))
        n2=int(input(print('Escoge tu segundos numero')))
        ress=n1+n2
        print(f'El resultado de sumar {n1} + {n2} = {ress}')
        break
    elif op==2:
        try:
            n1=int(input(print('Escoge tu primer numero')))
            n2=int(input(print('Escoge tu segundo numero')))
            ress=n1-n2
            print(f'El resultado de restar {n1} - {n2} = {ress}')
        except:
            print('Error al indicar numero intente')
        break
    elif op==3:
        n1=int(input(print('Escoge tu primer numero')))
        n2=int(input(print('Escoge tu segundo numero')))
        ress=n1*n2
        print(f'El resultado de Multiplicar {n1} X {n2} = {ress}')
        break
    elif op==4:
        n1=int(input(print('Escoge tu primer numero')))
        n2=int(input(print('Escoge tu segundo numero')))
        ress=n1/n2
        print(f'El resultado de dividir {n1} / {n2} = {ress}')
        break
    elif op==5:
        print('Vuelve pronto!!')
        break
    else:
        print('Numero no encontrado, ¡Intente de nuevo!')
        break

Se que son los break lo que lo finaliza, pero si no los pongo me dan un ciclo infinito en esa operación helpmee

Necesitas consultar la documentación de print y la de input. Ya que no deberías usar print dentro de input. Solo pon tu código dentro del while y quita los break.
Mira que simple queda tu código (ignorando validaciones y manejo de excepciones):
while True:
    n1 = int(input('Escoge tu primer numero'))
    n2 = int(input('Escoge tu segundo numero'))
    op = int(input('Escoje una opción'+'\n1.-Suma'+'\n2.-Resta'+'\n3.-Multiplicación'+'\n4.-Division'+'\n"5/0".-Salir'))
    if op==1:
        ress=n1+n2
        print(f'El resultado de sumar {n1} + {n2} = {ress}')
    elif op==2:
        ress=n1-n2
        print(f'El resultado de restar {n1} - {n2} = {ress}')
    elif op==3:
        ress=n1*n2
        print(f'El resultado de Multiplicar {n1} X {n2} = {ress}')
    elif op==4:
        ress=n1/n2
        print(f'El resultado de dividir {n1} / {n2} = {ress}')
    elif op == 0 or op == 5:
        print('Vuelve pronto!!')
        break
    else:
        print('Numero no encontrado, ¡Intente de nuevo!')


:0 no sabía que se podía poner texto en un input sin necesitar el print, pensé que era algo como java, muchas gracias, lo de la excepción fue porque quería probarlas jejej

Con muy pocas modificacioines, tu código sale marchando.
msjPrimer = 'Escoge tu primer numero'
msjSegun  = 'Escoge tu segundos numero'

op = 1
while op != 5:
    op = int( input( 'Escoje una opción' + '\n1.-Suma' + '\n2.-Resta' + '\n3.-Multiplicación' + '\n4.-Division' + '\n"5/0".-Salirs' ))
    if op == 1:
        n1 = int( input( msjPrimer ))
        n2 = int( input( msjSegun ))
        ress = n1 + n2
        print( f'El resultado de sumar {n1} + {n2} = {ress}' )
    elif op == 2:
        try:
            n1 = int( input( msjPrimer ))
            n2 = int( input(  msjSegun ))
            ress = n1 - n2
            print( f'El resultado de restar {n1} - {n2} = {ress}' )
        except:
            print( 'Error al indicar numero intente' )
    elif op==3:
        n1 = int( input( msjPrimer ))
        n2 = int( input( msjSegun ))
        ress = n1 * n2
        print( f'El resultado de Multiplicar {n1} X {n2} = {ress}' )
    elif op==4:
        n1 = int( input( msjPrimer ))
        n2 = int( input( msjSegun ))
        ress = n1 / n2
        print( f'El resultado de dividir {n1} / {n2} = {ress}' )
    elif op == 5:
        print( 'Vuelve pronto!!' )
    else:
        print( 'Numero no encontrado, ¡Intente de nuevo!' )

Como puedes ver, lo primero que hice, fue cambiar la ubicación del pedido de entrada al usuario, colocandolo dentro del while, para que de esta forma, cada vez que terminas una operación, te vuelva al menú inicial.
Luego cambié la condición del while, para que en caso de ingresar "5", la ejecución salga del mismo, lo único que resta, es quitar odos los break, que como bien comentas, son los que terminaban la ejecución.
PD: agregua las variables msjPrimer y msjSegun, solo para no tener que escribir tanto, no son imprescindibles.
Edición: quité los print que estaban dentro de los input, siguiendo la corrección de Mateo.

Hola muchas gracias, pero tengo una duda, cuando al objeto op le pusiste el valor de 1 , ¿por qué fue? y también porque en tu caso cuando quitaste los breaks no se te hizo un ciclo infinito en esa misma operación, disculpa la pregunta

El valor "1", es simplemente para que se cumpla la condición del while y entre en el, podrías ser cualquier valor (menos "5"), con respecto a los break, podríamos decir que está en un ciclo infinito, solo que si ingresas "5", la condición del while no se cumple y sales.

Al darle el valor de 1 es como si fuera un do while
